# Table Cell Height - Is there some minimum size one must adhere too?

Tags: html, html-table

The following is a 3 x 3 table:

```
<html>
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
<style>
div.table_div {overflow:scroll;width:378px;height:117px;position:relative;}
table.TheTable {width:361px;height:100px;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #000000;}
td.TheTableColumnCell {text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;border:1px solid #000000;}
</style>

<div class="table_div" id="table_div">
<table class="TheTable">
<tr id='firstTr'>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="TheTableColumnCell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Of note:

a) The table width is 361px because: 119px for each cell (119 x 3 = 357).  Then add 4px for the four borders.

b) The table height is 100px because: 32px for each cell (32 x 3 = 96).  Then add 4px for the four borders.

c) The div tag.  For my windows settings, the scrollbar width/height is 17px.  This is why you see the div width and height 378px (361 + 17) and 117px (100 + 17).  The purpose for the div is in case I actually have to scroll (in my 3x3 example, I don't really have to).

In summary: This is a 3x3 fixed-width/height table.  If you cut-and-paste that code into an html file and open it in your browser, you'll see the scrollbars, but neither will actually allow you to scroll (because I have the widths/heights set to show everything without scrolling).

**The problem:**

Do the following:

Instead of making the height of each cell 32px, make them 16px.  So, the height for **table.TheTable** should be changed to 52px (instead of 100px).  The height for **div.table_div** should be changed to 69px (instead of 117px) - again, my scrollbar height is 17px.

The vertical scrollbar, while always visible, now scrolls.  I can't fit everything now?  But I thought my calculations were correct?  The magic number seems to be 22px.  Less than 22px (height) I get a scrollbar that scrolls.  Greater than 22px, I get a scrollbar that doesn't scroll.  **If the div tag is correctly calculated, the scrollbars shouldn't scroll.  How do I avoid that for heights less than 22px?**

EDIT: The overflow:scroll is necessary.  I pulled this HTML out of a larger set a code.  In the real code the table is much larger.  The div tag allows me to show a certain amount of cells, and I can scroll to see the rest.  It's when I started playing with height's less than 22px, that's when I discovered the issue.  As it messes with some other things I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Problem has now become the font size/line height:

http://jsfiddle.net/EZ6q2/1/

You will need to reduce font size:

http://jsfiddle.net/EZ6q2/2/

or Line Height
http://jsfiddle.net/EZ6q2/3/

**In Response To Your Comment**

White space is still content and will count as text on a line. Completely emptying the cell also fixes the problem in Fire Fox. Be wary of this as some browsers my completely collapse empty cells (I've experienced this in some older browsers, IE 6 perhaps).

http://jsfiddle.net/EZ6q2/5/

**A Little More Follow Up**

The "padding" you refer to is the line height. From what I understand from [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) this is determined by metrics contained within the font its self and by default is a proportion of the font size, which is why changing the font size works. Changing the line height gives you an absolute result.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ6q2/8/)

Comment: Ya know, before posting here I thought it might be related to font-size as I remember playing around with that exact keyword.  I thought I tried that (but was using px instead of em).  I also figured that with no text whatsoever, why was it affecting me?  Anyhow, when I get home I'll try your suggestion.  I definitely could have messed something up.  And to all, I like this jsfiddle.net site ... looks pretty cool!  Thanks a lot for your time, can't wait to try it out.

Comment: Setting the font-size worked.  Green check-mark for you.  Thanks a lot.  Thinking about it, I did mess with font-size, but it was with the div tags I have in the "real code" (not shown here).  The only open question I have in my mind is where does the "5px" come from?  Meaning, if I want to have my cells have a height of 16px, my font-size can't be greater than 11px.  Maybe some type of default padding?  I'll have to play around.  I thought I read somewhere that the default text size is 16px, so I figured I could have 16px font-size with a cell height of 16px.  Anyhow, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

take

```
overflow:scroll
```

off div.table_div

if you want it too still have the horozontial scroll bar replace it with

```
overflow-x:scroll
```

also you will want the height a little bigger to compensate for the scroll bar size (it is about 26px iir)

Comment: The overflow:scroll is necessary though.  I pulled this HTML out of a larger set a code.  In the real code the table is much larger.  The div tag allows me to show a certain amount of cells, and I can scroll to see the rest.

Comment: if you only want one of the scroll bars use overflow-x:scroll or overflow-y:scroll

Comment: First, thanks for your help.  I really appreciate it.  I do need both scrollbars actually.  This is part of a larger table that includes a frozen first column and header.  And the grid actually has div tags which Are overlayed with a colored background.  This is sort of like a readonly display of a schedule control.  So theres 24 cells width wise (24 hours) and potentially a lot of 'users' in the first column (not displayed here).  The smaller heights were destroying my top calculations (for the div overlay).  I narrowed down the issue for the sake of posting here.

Comment: so the problem is that the div inside the table cell has scroll bars? and you are using the table in the overlayed divs to center text because the better way to do that is with line-height unless you are planning to have more than one line of text in it

Comment: I definitely appreciate the help, so I upped your answer 1.  Hopefully you get some points.

Answer (score 1):

I created the http://jsfiddle.net/EZ6q2/

With your HTML + CSS.

I can't see what the issue is, can you edit it to your example then edit your question with the revised JSfiddle?

**Note**
I have removed the `overflow:scroll` property from your table, as you have it a fixed height/width.

Comment: The overflow:scroll is necessary though.  I pulled this HTML out of a larger set a code.  In the real code the table is much larger.  The div tag allows me to show a certain amount of cells, and I can scroll to see the rest.  When I'm near my computer I will add to this.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the help, so I upped your answer 1.  Hopefully you get some points.